# Авторизация VK API и приложение на Python

Tags: python, авторизация, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Помогите пройти авторизацию на python. Есть такой код:

```
def main():
    webbrowser.open('http://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id='+APP_ID+'&        scope='+SETTINGS+'&redirect_uri='+REDIRECT_URI+'&display='+DISPLAY+'&response_type=token')
```

В браузере вводятся логин/пароль и запрашивается разрешение, но как после всего этого вытянуть из браузера токен и идентификатор пользователя?

Comment: На какой платформе всё происходит?

Comment: win7, 64 bit

Comment: Т.е. это локальное приложение, запускаемое пользователем на своём компьютере?

Comment: да, именно

Comment: Тьфу-ты, показалось, что вопрос по C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я некоторое время назад решил вашу проблему. Вкратце, можно парсить странички авторизации и отправлять формы без использования браузера. Подробное описание решения можно прочитать в [статье](http://habrahabr.ru/post/143972/). Исходники модуля лежат на [github](https://github.com/dzhioev/vk_api_auth). Модуль использует только стандартные модули Python, поэтому должен работать без лишних телодвижений практически везде.

Comment: хм, спасибо за ссылку. статью видел, но особо не всматривался, показалась слишком хардкорной для новичка

Answer (score 6):

Смысл авторизации через сторонний сервис (в данном случае OAuth 2) ледующий:

1. На сервисе (в данном случае ВК) необходимо зарегистрировать приложение и получить ключ API.
2. После этого приложение (сайт) могут делать запрос личных данных пользователя у строннего сервиса через этот самый API, для чего:

   - перенаправить пользователя (браузер пользователя посредством посылки ему HTTP ответа 302 Redirect) по **специально сформированной ссылке** (из Вашего сообщения) на сервис предоставляющий API;
   - пользователь там произведёт какие-то действия, предположительно авторизуется и разрешит доступ к данным;
   - по завершении действий пользователь будет перенаправлен сторонним сервисом посредством всё того же 302 Redirect на URL переданный в параметрах **специально сформированной ссылки** (в данном случае это `'&redirect_uri='+REDIRECT_URI`).
3. Пользователь попадает по той самой ссылке возврата Ваш на сайт. И если пользователь согласился предоставить свои данные, хранящиеся на стороннем сервисе, Вашему сайту - то эта ссылка в GET параметрах будет содержать ключ доступа к данным пользователя на этом стороннем сервисе, в противном случае она будет содержать код отказа (см. документацию на целевом сервисе).

В положительной ситуации требуется сохранить этот ключ доступа и используя его и ключ API в дальнейшем прямыми запросами приложения к сервису получать необходимую информацию. В зависимости от протокола этот ключ доступа может использоваться для получения другого ключа с которым уже можно будет оперировать с данными пользователя. В любом случае после третьего шага участие пользователя уже не требуется и все данные нужно пjлучать прямыми запросами Вашего сайта к стороннему, например через `urllib2.urlopen`.

Это общий принцип действия, конкретные нюансы следует уточнять в документации для разработчиков от конкретного сервиса. В данном случае это [Авторизация сайтов на ВКонтакте](http://vk.com/developers.php?oid=-1&p=%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2).

Answer (score 4):

Два варианта.

1. Советский. Перед отправкой пользователя с браузером на сайт, рассказать ему "сейчас у вас откроется браузер, вы там введите свой пароль, со всем согласитесь, и потом скопируйте сюда в нашу программу всю адресную строку ручками".
2. Буржуазный. Использовать некую среду, внутри которой есть свой компонент браузера. Будь то родное приложение под Windows, написанное на Delphi, или под Мак на XCode. В таком случае, приложение имеет власть над содержащимся внутри него браузером, и может в нужный момент получить из него адресную строку.

Comment: а можно вообще без браузера обойтись?

Comment: Нет. Но сойдёт любой, с минимальным функционалом - даже WAP браузер мобильника. Надо будет открыть страницу VK, принять куки, выполнить пару редиректов, отправить форму POST'ом. Кажется, даже без JavaScript можно обойтись.

Comment: Я в Python не очень, но вот, вроде бы, решение. Примочка для питона, чтобы работать с компонентом браузера: [pywebkitgtk](http://code.google.com/p/pywebkitgtk/)

Comment: спасибо, не охота в самом начале обучения программированию лезть в такие дебри

Comment: Да, дебри ацкие : ) Поэтому часто встречается 1-й вариант.

Comment: Не сто́ит бояться трудностей, иначе программированию не научитесь, только копипасте, а такие кодеры никому не нужны - их и так слишком много. Всегда лучше потратить время и понять принцип, чем писать не понятно что в надежде, что «работает - и пускай работает»…

Comment: Можно и без браузера на самом деле. Да, это будет не OAuth и да, придётся немного попарсить страницы авторизации.

Comment: понравилось "приложение имеет власть над содержащимся внутри него браузером"

Answer (score 2):

Токен придет в URL запроса на `REDIRECT_URI`. Отсюда: [Авторизация клиентских приложений](http://vk.com/pages?oid=-1&p=%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)

> **Получение access_token**
>
> После успешной авторизации приложения
> браузер пользователя будет
> перенаправлен по адресу `REDIRECT_URI`,
> указанному при открытии диалога
> авторизации. При этом ключ доступа к
> `API access_token` и другие параметры
> будут передана в URL-фрагменте ссылки:
> `http://REDIRECT_URI#access_token= 533bacf01e11f55b536a565b57531ad114461ae8736d6506a3&expires_in=86400&user_id=8492`

Comment: это то я в курсе, но этот url есть только в браузере. а как вытянуть то?

Comment: По-хорошему - вы их получите как параметры GET-запроса в веб-приложении, которое висит на `REDIRECT_URI`. В противном случае, придётся вытягивать руками из урла в открытом браузере. Насколько знаю, это не совсем тривиальная задача. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358224/get-url-from-webbrowser-in-python

Comment: а есть ли более удобный способ авторизации, да и вообще обращения к API? я пробовал https://oauth.vk.com/access_token, удобно что json ответы, но не доступны многие вызовы api

Comment: Не могу сходу сказать, нужно читать документацию VK API.

Comment: Определитесь, какими методами API будет оперировать ваше приложение. Если какой-то из них доступен только Standalone приложению, придётся заморачиваться с получением token'а, как я описал в ответе.